# Laravel 5 remove null collection properties

Tags: laravel

I have a Model named `estate` and I have many fields in it.

I'm using a single view for `create` and `show` methods in the respective Controller.

To do this in the `create` method I created an empty collection:

```
$estate = collect(new Estate);

$estate->id                  = null;
$contact->area_name          = null;
$contact->zone_name          = null;
$estate->tipologia           = null;
$estate->metratura           = null;
$estate->external_id         = null;
$estate->descrizione         = null;
$estate->piano               = null;
$estate->price               = null;
$estate->via                 = null;
$estate->zone_id             = null;
$estate->area_id             = null;
$estate->riscaldamento       = null;
$estate->condizione_immobile = null;
$estate->vista               = null;
```

I would like to remove all those `null` values while creating an empty Collection but I need this to be  **in the Controller**, but if I do:

```
$estate = collect(new Estate);
```

without any `null` key it gives an error `Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.` (and is actually correct). How do I set them default to null?

Comment: You may initialize properties with empty string rather null in this case.

Comment: @Mr.Web did you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a filter:

```
$filteredEstate = $estate->filter(function($value, $key) {
    return  $value != null;
});
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work, it returns the same error as "id" (for example) is not set...

Comment: @Mr.Web why you want to remove `NULL` ? You can replace it easily in your controller. What's the reason you want to do this?

Comment: Instead of having to set all those keys to `null` I wanted a method to return ANY key to null in that portion of the controller. That's all. `$estate->myfriend` does not exist so it should return null instead of error.

Comment: @Mr.Web check `flatMap()` in here `https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#creating-collections`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isset()`. Like this:

```
isset($estate->vista) ? doSomething() : echo '...';
```

If you would need this in a controller, you could still do either this:

```
// Executing a function (example: doSomethingWith() or doNothing())
isset($estate->visita) ? doSomethingWith($estate->visita) : doNothing();

// Or set a value
$variable = isset($estate->visita) ? $estate->visita : 'string of text';
```

or you could use a more common if-statement:

```
if(isset($estate->visita))
{
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I need it in the Controller

Comment: What do you think, @Mr.Web?

Comment: I think is not what I asked. Do you want to try read the question again? Tks

Comment: I think you're trying to achieve something that's just not there. If a value were `null`, at least the key would exist. But that's neither the case. Therefore I believe that `isset()` is your best solution atm. Or at least, to the extend of my expertise.

Answer (score -2):

try using `empty` like this:

```
@if(!empty($estate->piano)) //do_someThisng    @else //do_something_or_nothing    @endif
```

if you want to do this in controller

```
foreach($estate as $e)
{
   if($e == null)
   {
       unset($estate[$s]);
   }
}
```

I hope this code works for you, I used it for something else but similar to your work, but I don't know is this working in this way or not.

Comment: I need it in the Controller